# iOS React-Native-Image-Resizer Error: Image uri invalid

Tags: react-native, image-resizing

I am currently attempting to use react-native-image-resizer to batch-resize images before uploading.

This is my image resize function followed closely to the docs:

```
const resizeImage = async (base64Str) => {
  try {
    const resizedImage = await ImageResizer.createResizedImage(
      base64Str,
      1280,
      1280,
      'JPEG',
      80,
      0,
      undefined,
      false,
      {
        mode: 'contain',
        onlyScaleDown: true,
      }
    );

    console.log('Resized image URI:', resizedImage.uri);
    return resizedImage.uri;
  } catch (error) {
    console.error('Failed to resize image:', error);
    return null;
  }
}
```

When console logging the `base64Str` it is coming in with the right prepend according to the docs: `data:image/jpeg;base64,/9j/...`.

However, no matter what I do I keep getting the `Error: Image uri invalid`.

I have followed the following [issue](https://github.com/bamlab/react-native-image-resizer/issues/328) but was not able to get any of those solutions to work either.

Does anyone have an idea of a fix, workaround, or error I am making?